# App logout in background

Tags: android, user-interface, counter, logout

Aim: For App to logout user in background, hence when user select HOME button to exit app. Counter will start and logout user. Help greatly appreciated

Issue: Unable to Run

```
public void IdleLogout(){    
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    @Override
    protected @ onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Timer starts count when Home Button is selected
        int seconds = 60;
        timer.schedule(new StartCounting(), 60*1000);
    }
}
class StartCounting extends TimerTask{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent_login= new Intent(context, RootActivity.class);
        //CLOSE ALL OTHER ACTIVITIES AND BRING THE ACTIVITY BEING LAUNCHED TO THE TOP
        intent_login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent_login);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use alarm? Also I hope showing Root activity is really logout for the user

Comment: Yes, it does. The main Login function is within the RootActivity. But I dont see any error within the code

Answer (score 0):

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;    

@override                           
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_nocticeboard);
scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(); 
IdleLogout();// if you want to run it at activity statrt up
 } 

public void IdleLogout(){ 

scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

Intent intent_login= new Intent(context, RootActivity.class);

    intent_login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent_login);

        }
    }, 0, 60*10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

 }
```

Comment: How do you resolve Timeunit into a variable?

Comment: I have just imported ..import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

Comment: why did you put  }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);?? wouldnt that be a syntax error?

Comment: and should ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();  be under public void IdleLogout(){ ??

Comment: 0 and 10 are delay time and repetatin interval respectively and yes the shedular should be outside your function just like any other object you can declare outside onCreate method and initialize it inside onCreate Method

Comment: I dont quite get you

Comment: and should ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;